# Converting map coordinates of a rotated grid.

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm trying to makes a stellar map, but I'm using a coordinate system different from the standard. I have coordinates in the normal system, but I need them in mine. This equates to rotating the carteesian grid 45 degrees.

Worst case scenario I can just brute force this, but I'd rather just be able to convert with an equation so I'm looking for how to convert a position's x,y coordinate from one grid to another grid when the difference between the two grids are one is spun clockwise so that centerlines are at a 45 degree angle to each other.

side note: Because I don't know if they original coordinates are south or north oriented, the rotation may actually be rotated 225 degrees rather than just 45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) is basicaly what you want.

For rotating a vector
$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} $
by the angle $\alpha$, just multiply it with the matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) &-\sin(\alpha) \\ \sin(\alpha) &\cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix}$.

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} x_{new} \\ y_{new} \end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) &-\sin(\alpha) \\ \sin(\alpha) &\cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x_{old} \\ y_{old} \end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix} x_{old} \cdot \cos(\alpha) - y_{old} \cdot \sin(\alpha) \\ x_{old} \cdot \sin(\alpha) + y_{old} \cdot \cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

In case you are not familiar with vectors, this means:

\begin{align}
x_{new} &= x_{old} \cdot \cos(\alpha) - y_{old} \cdot \sin(\alpha) \\
y_{new} &= x_{old} \cdot \sin(\alpha) + y_{old} \cdot \cos(\alpha)
\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain it more simply. I assume when you say vector you just mean the original x,y coordinate... and I have no idea how to deal sine and cosine...

Comment: I added an example. Are you familiar with matrix-vector multiplication? If not, just use the formulat I wrote down.

Comment: I don't know if you program, but could I do this in Javascript -- var NewX = (Math.cos(45) * -Math.sin(45)) * OldX? Or is that wrong?

Comment: I'm not very familar with much mathematics beyond basic algebra. I ran away from it as soon as I could unfortunately.

Comment: I don't do Javascript but this seems right. Updated answer again for a vector-free formular that can be transformed to code directly.

Comment: Thanks I really do need to learn this stuff cuz i comes up far too often in the stuff I mess with ^.^

Comment: I just looked up [math.sin in Javascipt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sin) ad it seems that you have to convert your angle from degree to radian first. 45 degree equals $\frac{1}{4} \cdot \pi$ so you will need something like `var NewX = (Math.cos(Math.PI / 4) * OldX -Math.sin(Math.PI / 4)) * OldY`

Comment: ahh. I missed that. Again thanks. I would have missed that and been confused for a few hours lol

Comment: This just happens all the time :)